# javafx utility method to load FXML file

Tags: java, javafx

I have several instances where I want to load the same FXML file in order to capture some information.

Ideally, this would be a case for developing a utility method i.e. write once, use many times.

This is a current example, using a `private` method within a class:

```
private ServiceEvent_NewController loadServiceEvent_Stage(Stage primaryStage)
{
   ServiceEvent_NewController controller = null;

    try
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/View/ServiceEvent_New.fxml") );
        Parent root = loader.load(); 

        // Create the dialog Stage.
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);

        controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);            

    }
    catch (IOException npe)
    {
        String message = npe.getMessage();
        System.out.println(message);
    }                

    return controller;
}
```

I have a utility class ( `public final class LM_Utility` ).
If I attempt to create a method to load the FXML here using:

```
public static ServiceEvent_NewController loadServiceEvent_Stage(Stage primaryStage)
```

the compiler complains `"non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context"`.

Is there some way to create a suitable utility method to load such files, so I can, "write once and use many times"?

Comment: have you tryed ServiceEvent_NewController.class.getResource("...")?

Answer (score 1):

`getClass()` returns the runtime class the method contains.

If you do not need effects of using a location relative to extending classes, you could simply replace

```
getClass()
```

with

```
LM_Utility.class
```

which is an expression for the `Class` object for the `LM_Utility` class, which is what `getClass()` would return in a non-static method, since  `LM_Utility` is `final`.

Of course you probably should pass the resource path of the fxml file to the method and also use a interface or a abstract class containing the `setDialogStage` instead of hardcoding a object type. You could use a type parameter `<T extends ControllerInterface>` to allow you to use the real controller type as target for an assignment. (Note though that at runtime this assignment will still effectively contain a cast to the target type.)